# string transformation with regex

Tags: regex, scala

I have the following string:

```
val s1:String = "1. my line 1\n2. my other line\n3. my 3rd line\n4. and so on"
```

Now, I want transform at other:

```
val s2:String = "<b>1. </b>my line 1\n<b>2. </b>my other line\n<b>3. </b>my 3rd line\n<b>4. </b>and so on"
```

What is better way to do it?

Comment: A better way than what? Are you asking for the regex substitution string or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s1.replaceAll("""(?m)^(\d+\. )""", "<b>$1</b>")
```

Read: Find all occurences of "beginning of the line followed by one or more digits followed by a dot followed by a space" and replace them with the matched substring surrounded by `<b>` and `</b>`.

The `(?m)` bit makes it so that `^` means "beginning of line" instead of "beginning of string". The `"""` are so that there's no need to double escape.

Comment: And, also enclosing lines with <i> and </i>. Example:
`"<b>1. </b><i>my line 1</i>\n<b>2. </b><i>my other line</i>\n<b>3. </b><i>my 3rd line</i>\n<b>4. </b><i>and so on</i>"`